# Couchdb _design/doc/_update/push not working as object

Tags: javascript, json, couchdb, couchapp

I want to use an existing Couchdb document, to deep-merge some data on this request

Request:: 
`curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST http://localhost/couch/ddb/_design/data/_update/push2/cap1 -d '{"51" : 5, "65" : 2}'`

Database Document::
`{65: [[]], 51: [[]]};`

Update function::
`function(doc, req) {
var d = req.body; 
for(var key in doc.x2) {
doc.x2[key][0].push(d[key]);
}; 
return [doc,'added'];}"`

The problem is that `req.body` that contains the data shows up as `String` not as a `JSON object` making it impossible to select the value

The result to the query should be:: 
`{65: [[2]], 51: [[5]]};`

Everthing else works fine, expect `req.body` is a `String` and not an `Object`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, found my own answer. Wasn't hard:

`var d = req.body;` >> `var d = JSON.parse(req.body);` and `d` becomes `Object`

Comment: Yep. Common mistake. :) The `req.body` value could be anything--not just JSON--so CouchDB doesn't auto-parse it. Glad you fixed it!